# fill_null() values with other columns data

Tags: python, dataframe, multiple-columns, fillna, python-polars

i have a question regarding fill null values, is it possible to backfill data from other columns as in pandas?

Working pandas example on how to backfill data :

```py
df.loc[:, ['A', 'B', 'C']] = df[['A', 'B', 'C']].fillna(
    value={
        'A': df['D'],
        'B': df['D'],
        'C': df['D'],
    }
)
```

Polars example as i tried to backfill data from column D to column A if the value is null, but it's not working:

```
df = pl.DataFrame(
        {"date": ["2020-01-01 00:00:00", "2020-01-07 00:00:00", "2020-01-14 00:00:00"],
        "A": [3, 4, 7],
        "B": [3, 4, 5],
        "C": [0, 1, 2],
        "D": [1, 2, 5]})
df = df.with_column(pl.col("date").str.strptime(pl.Datetime, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
date_range = df.select(pl.arange(df["date"][0], df["date"]
                        [-1] + 1, step=1000*60*60*24).cast(pl.Datetime).alias("date"))
df = (date_range.join(df, on="date", how="left"))
df['D'] = df['D'].fill_null("forward")
print(df)
df[:, ['A']] = df[['A']].fill_null({
    'A': df['D']
    }
)
print(df)
```

Kind regards,
Tom

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the example you show and the accomponied pandas code. A `fillna` doesn't fill any null values, because the other columns are also `NaN`. So I am going to assume that you want to fill missing values by values of another column that doesn't have missing values, but correct me if I am wrong.

```py
import polars as pl
from polars import col

df = pl.DataFrame({
    "a": [0, 1, 2, 3, None, 5, 6, None, 8, None],
    "b": range(10),
})

out = df.with_columns([
    pl.when(col("a").is_null()).then(col("b")).otherwise(col("a")).alias("a"),
    pl.when(col("a").is_null()).then(col("b").shift(1)).otherwise(col("a")).alias("a_filled_lag"),
    pl.when(col("a").is_null()).then(col("b").mean()).otherwise(col("a")).alias("a_filled_mean")

])

print(out)
```

In the example above, we use a `when -> then -> othwerwise` expression to fill missing values by another columns values. Think about `if else expressions` but then on whole columns.

I gave 3 examples, one where we fill on that value, one where we fill with the lagged value, and one where we fill with the mean value of the other column.

The snippet above produces:

```
shape: (10, 4)
┌─────┬─────┬──────────────┬───────────────┐
│ a   ┆ b   ┆ a_filled_lag ┆ a_filled_mean │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---          ┆ ---           │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64          ┆ f64           │
╞═════╪═════╪══════════════╪═══════════════╡
│ 0   ┆ 0   ┆ 0            ┆ 0.0           │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1   ┆ 1   ┆ 1            ┆ 1             │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2   ┆ 2   ┆ 2            ┆ 2             │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3   ┆ 3   ┆ 3            ┆ 3             │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ ... ┆ ... ┆ ...          ┆ ...           │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 5   ┆ 5   ┆ 5            ┆ 5             │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 6   ┆ 6   ┆ 6            ┆ 6             │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 7   ┆ 7   ┆ 6            ┆ 4.5           │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 8   ┆ 8   ┆ 8            ┆ 8             │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 9   ┆ 9   ┆ 8            ┆ 4.5           │
└─────┴─────┴──────────────┴───────────────┘
```

Answer (score 1):

Polars provides the user with [`pl.Expr.fill_null`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.fill_null.html) to fill missing values. It is used as follows.

```py
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame({
    "a": [0, 1, 2, 3, None, 5, 6, None, 8, None],
    "b": range(10),
})

(
    df
    .with_columns(
        pl.col("a").fill_null(pl.col("b")).alias("a_filled"),
        pl.col("a").fill_null(pl.col("b").shift()).alias("a_filled_lag"),
        pl.col("a").fill_null(pl.col("b").mean()).alias("a_filled_mean"),
    )
)
```

```
shape: (10, 5)
┌──────┬─────┬──────────┬──────────────┬───────────────┐
│ a    ┆ b   ┆ a_filled ┆ a_filled_lag ┆ a_filled_mean │
│ ---  ┆ --- ┆ ---      ┆ ---          ┆ ---           │
│ i64  ┆ i64 ┆ i64      ┆ i64          ┆ f64           │
╞══════╪═════╪══════════╪══════════════╪═══════════════╡
│ 0    ┆ 0   ┆ 0        ┆ 0            ┆ 0.0           │
│ 1    ┆ 1   ┆ 1        ┆ 1            ┆ 1.0           │
│ 2    ┆ 2   ┆ 2        ┆ 2            ┆ 2.0           │
│ 3    ┆ 3   ┆ 3        ┆ 3            ┆ 3.0           │
│ null ┆ 4   ┆ 4        ┆ 3            ┆ 4.5           │
│ 5    ┆ 5   ┆ 5        ┆ 5            ┆ 5.0           │
│ 6    ┆ 6   ┆ 6        ┆ 6            ┆ 6.0           │
│ null ┆ 7   ┆ 7        ┆ 6            ┆ 4.5           │
│ 8    ┆ 8   ┆ 8        ┆ 8            ┆ 8.0           │
│ null ┆ 9   ┆ 9        ┆ 8            ┆ 4.5           │
└──────┴─────┴──────────┴──────────────┴───────────────┘
```

Answer (score 0):

The fillna() method is used to fill null values in pandas.

```
df['D'] = df['D'].fillna(df['A'].mean())
```

The above code will replace null values of `D` column with the mean value of `A` column.

Comment: OP asked for a solution in python-polars which achieves the same as the pandas `fillna` function. You just posted a pandas solution.

Comment: I did not see the updated question, since the time I answered.